# Amazon CroudFront の使い所

Tags: aws, amazon-s3

現在, JavaScript/Image/CSS を S3 に置いて HTML だけは動的なため別サーバーにあるような作りのサイトを運営しています。

CroudFront を使えば、これらアセットをキャッシュできるので高速になる、というのはわかったのですが、実際の所、S3 でも十分な速度で低価格なのであまり CroudFront の必要性を感じることができません。

そこまで大規模でないサイトで CroudFront を導入することに何かメリットはありますか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

世界中のいろんな場所からアクセスされる可能性があり、かつどの場所にも高速にアセットを配信したい場合には、CloudFrontを使うと良いでしょう。

S3はリージョンへのアクセスになりますから、たとえば東京リージョンのS3を使用した場合、太平洋を渡ったアメリカ西海岸からアクセスすると、どうしても転送にかかる時間の分は遅くなってしまいます。

ソレに対してCloudFrontでは、アクセスしたユーザーに物理的に近いキャッシュサーバーを自動で提供してくれます。そのためユーザーが世界中どこからアクセスしても、ネットワークによる大きな遅延が無くアセットを取得できることがメリットとなります。